# How to get an Address value from a String value in Java

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

Does exist a method to get an Address value from a String value in Java? I have a database with a column "Place" where i put my addresses in String format. To get the String I do:

```
    Place p = PlacePicker.getPlace(this, data);
    String sPlace = p.getAddress().toString();
```

But I didn't find a way to do the opposite, if it exists. 
In a Activity I put all my values in the database.
In another Activity I search for some specific rows with a query; then I need an Address or a LatLng to set a marker on a Map at the specified address.
I know if I put the lat and the long in my database i can easy do this, but I want to know if it's possible with a String address.